# Kubenetes Pod showing status "Completed" without any jobs

Tags: kubernetes

I'm hosting an Angular website that connects to a C#-backend inside a Kubernetes Cluster. When I use a certain function on the website that I can't describe in more detail, the pod shows status "Completed", then goes into "CrashLoopBackOff" and then restarts. The problem is, there are no jobs set up for this Pod (in fact, I didn't even know Jobs are a thing until one hour ago). So my main question would be: How can a Pod go into the "Completed" status without running any jobs?

My .yaml file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-demo
  namespace: my-namespace
  labels:
    app: my-demo
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      name: my-demo-pod
      labels:
        app: my-demo
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        "beta.kubernetes.io/os": windows
      containers:
      - name: my-demo-container
        image: myregistry.azurecr.io/my.demo:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 1
            memory: 800M
          requests:
            cpu: .1
            memory: 300M
        ports:
          - containerPort: 80
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: my-registry-secret
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-demo
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-demo-service
  namespace: my-namespace
spec:
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    name: my-demo-port
  selector:
    app: my-demo
```

Comment: What kind of container are you using to serve the Angular site? can you share the Dockerfile or more details on the container itself?

Comment: @wolmi In the Dockerfile I'm only copying together a bunch of build artifacts, but I can share my .yaml

Comment: Could you post output of `kubectl describe pod <pod_name>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Completed` status indicates that the application called by the `cmd` or `ENTRYPOINT` exited with a non-error (i.e. `0`) status code. This `Completed`->`CrashLoopBackoff`->`Running` cycle usually indicates that the process called on the container start doesn't daemonize itself and exits, which Kubernetes sees as the process 'completing', hence the status.

Check that your `ENTRYPOINT` in your Dockerfile or your `cmd` in your pod template are calling the right process (with the appropriate flags) for the process to be daemonized. You can also check the logs for the previous pod (i.e. using `kubectl logs --previous`) to see what output the application gave

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer as it basically describes the root cause. What actually happened is that the application threw an exception which for some reason returns an exit code 0. Hence the confusing "Completed"-status on the container.